# what can I do to get out of a question ban in stack overflow site?

Tags: discussion, post-ban

I have gone through this [helpful link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th)

I understood that to get out of a question ban I need to improve my old posts but my question is that I have posted only 4 questions and I got answers on all these question and I improved and modified these questions but still I am banned on stack overflow. I also tried to delete my questions but as it has answers I am unable to delete these posts. What else I need to do?

Comment: Deleting a question will not help. It still counts. And a deleted question can't get upvotes.

Comment: Oh k. But what else can I do to unbanned myself?

Comment: How many deleted questions do you have?

Comment: No questions I have deleted yet.

Comment: Were any of your questions deleted by others or the system?

Comment: No. But I had deleted one question on programmers which had -1 vote.

Comment: I ask because you have only 1 downvoted question.  I would be very suprised if that was sufficient for a Q-ban without deleted questions

Comment: Improving a question doesn't mean just making some changes to your syntax and grammar. It means adding detail and code, making it more understandable and easier to answer. You know - by making an effort.

Comment: @RichardTingle - one community deleted question.

Comment: @Oded Your point is acceptable. You may have gone through my question, many of my questions are not related code issue.

Comment: Then why did you ask them on SO? They are off-topic there. You got banned for a reason it seems. Frankly, how do we know that if you get out of the ban you will not continue asking such questions?

Comment: As I was new to the stack overflow and I had seen many questions like my questions so I posted here.

Comment: @Oded I'm curious; why is 1 deleted question enough to trigger a Q-ban? I know we don't know the exact formula, but in absence of other information that seems a bit odd.

Comment: @WendiKidd - It never is. But deletions, downvoted posts and zero upvotes would certainly be contributing.

Comment: Thanks every one who voted up to my SO questions. I am unbanned from posting questions. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's going to take a while.  You need to come to terms with that reality.  You're going to have to answer a LOT of questions and gain a LOT of reputation before you get unblocked.  It's not impossible, because I've done it myself.  But I probably answered 7 or 8 questions a day for a full month before it happened.  Contribute wisely, don't just throw bad answers out there because downvotes are gonna hurt you.

Comment: Wow, too true to be true ;) Another radical avatar, me gusta!

Comment: Thanks, I am unbanned from posting questions. :)